# typescript extend type of passed in function as React props

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I have a React component form (antd) which renders its two input fields and fires a submit event on button click with its two fields as callback parameters along with ANY other additional fields that can be passed and rendered as `ReactNode` as long as they are `Form.Item` antd components.

Antd `Form` component works as follows - it picks any `Form.Item` element it encounters and passes their value to the `onSubmit` Form function with a key as passed value to `name` field.

In my case I need to receive an argument of a function:

```
{
    name: 'task name',
    description: 'task description',
    statusId: 1,
    subtasks: [
        { name: 'subtask name 1' },
        { name: 'subtask name 2' }
    ]
}
```

So the main idea is that I want to fire this `onSubmit` callback with those 2 fields THIS component knows (`name`, `description`) along with any other fields that are rendered inside but this component isn't aware of.

```
// TaskForm.tsx

type Props = {
    taskId: number,
    renderSubtask: (subtaskId: number) => React.ReactNode,
    status: React.ReactNode
    onSubmit: <T extends Pick<TaskEntity, "name" | "description">>(data: T) => void;
    onCancel: () => void
};

export function TaskForm({taskId, renderSubtask, status, onSubmit, onCancel}: Props) {
    const task = useTask(taskId);
    return (
        <Form
            name="basic"
            colon={true}
            autoComplete="off"
      // ========THIS FUNCTION===========
            onFinish={<T extends Pick<TaskEntity, "name" | "description">>(values: T) => onSubmit({...values, id: taskId})}
      // ================================
        >
            <Form.Item label="Name" name="name" initialValue={task?.name}>
                <Input name="name"/>
            </Form.Item>

            <Form.Item label="Description" name="description" initialValue={task?.description}>
                <Input.TextArea name="description"/>
            </Form.Item>
            {task.subtasks.map(renderSubtask)}
            {status}
            <Row justify="center" gutter={50}>
                <Col>
                    <Button htmlType="submit" type="primary" size="large">
                        {task ? "Save changes" : "Create task"}
                    </Button>
                </Col>
                <Col>
                    <Button type="primary" size="large" onClick={onCancel}>Cancel</Button>
                </Col>
            </Row>
        </Form>
    );
};
```

The parent component (I omitted some intermediate components) that passes `onSubmit` callback function to `TaskForm` and that is aware of others components that are rendered inside `Form` and passed as parameters looks as follows:

```
// TaskColumn.tsx

export function TaskColumn({statusId}: TaskColumnProps) {
    const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
    const board = BoardModel.useCurrentBoard();
    const status = StatusModel.useStatus(statusId);
    const [isFormVisible, setIsFormVisible] = useState(false);

    const handleTaskSubmit = async (data: Omit<ITask, 'created'>) => {
        await dispatch(UpdateTaskModel.updateTask(data));
    };

    return (
        <div data-testid="task-column">
            <StatusRow
                title={status.name}
                before={<ChangeStatusColor color={status.color}/>}
                numberOfTasks={status.tasks.length}
            />
            {status.tasks.map(taskId => (
                <TaskForm
                    taskId={taskId}
                    renderSubtask={(subtaskId: number) => (
                        <SubtaskRow
                            subtaskId={subtaskId}
                            before={<ToggleSubtask subtaskId={subtaskId}/>}
                        />
                    )}
                    status={<StatusSelect statusIds={board.statuses}/>}
                    onSubmit={handleTaskSubmit}
                    onCancel={() => setIsFormVisible(false)}
                />
            ))}
        </div>
    );
};
```

So it passes `SubtaskRow` component which is rendered as a `Form.Item` component (don't include here, you got the idea).

Looks like I don't understand how `extends` type works (read documentation for several times). In the callback that I receive in `TaskForm` component I'm trying to say to Typescript that I want the passed in function to accept an object with AT LEAST two fields  - `name` and `description` AND ANY OTHER FIELD that parent component wishes to pass as render props `Form.Item`.

So in my case `Omit<ITask, 'created'>` means the next fields - `name`, `description`, `id`, `statusId` and `subtasks` (which are passed as `ReactNode`). Unfortunately, I get the next error:

> Type 'Pick<TaskEntity, "name" | "description">' is missing the following properties from type 'Omit<ITask, "created">': statusId, id, subtasks

But instead I want that function inside `TaskForm` to not care about other values that can be passed to this form.

How can I get the behavior I want from typescript?